# Comparing two files and display a matrix with 0 and 1 for not present or present

Tags: python, matrix

I'm new with python so i'm reaaally struggling in making a script.

So, what I need  is to make a comparison between two files. One file contains all proteins of some data base, the other contain only some of the proteins presents in the other file, because it belongs to a organism. So I need to know which proteins of this data base is present in my organism. For that I want to build a output like a matrix, with 0 and 1 referring to every protein present in the data base that may or may not be in my organism.

Does anybody have any idea of how could I do that?
I'm trying to use something like this

```
$ cat sorted.a
A
B
C
D
$ cat sorted.b
A
D
$ join  sorted.a sorted.b | sed 's/^/1 /' && join  -v 1 sorted.a sorted.b | sed 's/^/0 /'
1 A
1 D
0 B
0 C
```

But I'm not being able to use it because sometimes a protein is present but its not in the same line.

Here is a Example:

```
1-cysPrx_C
120_Rick_ant
14-03-2003
2-Hacid_dh
2-Hacid_dh_C
2-oxoacid_dh
2-ph_phosp
2CSK_N
2C_adapt
2Fe-2S_Ferredox
2H-phosphodiest
2HCT
2OG-FeII_Oxy
```

**Comparing with**

```
1-cysPrx_C
14-3-3
2-Hacid_dh
2-Hacid_dh_C
2-oxoacid_dh
2H-phosphodiest
2OG-FeII_Oxy
2OG-FeII_Oxy_3
2OG-FeII_Oxy_4
2OG-FeII_Oxy_5
2OG-Fe_Oxy_2
2TM
2_5_RNA_ligase2
```

Does anyone have an idea of how could I do that?
Thanks so far.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way in Python would be to read your organism file, and save each protein name to a set. Then open and iterate through your all_proteins file, for each name print it, check if that name is present in your organism set, and print a 0 or 1 appropriately.

Example code if your organism list is called 'prot_list':

```
with open(all_proteins_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        prot = line.strip()
        if prot in prot_list: num = 1
        else: num = 0
        print '%i %s' % (num, prot)
```

Comment: I already have a list with all proteins presents in my organism and a all_proteins file. But how could I check wich protein is present or not and print 0 and 1? that's my question.

Comment: I added some code to my answer. Also, I would use a set instead of a list to hold your organism's protein names. Membership lookup is much faster in a set than in a list, and for your case it doesn't seem like the order of the proteins in your list matters.